# Excel MDX - same period last month - totals

Tags: sql, excel, mdx

I have the following MDX expression which helps me to display the data for the 'same period last month' from the Cube PER DAY.

```
Filter( 
    [Date].[Date].[Date], 
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value >= 
          DateSerial(Year(DateAdd('m', -1, VBA![Date]())),
                     Month(DateAdd('m', -1, VBA![Date]())),
                     1
                    ) 
    AND [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Value < DateAdd('m', -1, VBA![Date]())
)
```

Now I would like to redo the code to display just the total for this period without  breaking it down per day. The reason for this is, that if for example I want to see the total number of active users for the same period last month I can't simply sum up the numbers of daily users as this will be higher than the real number of total users in this period (user may be active on more than one day and I just want to count him once for this period).

I tried chaning the code but nothing works so far. Any ideas?

Many thanks  in advance,
Maciej

Comment: Which levels does your date hierarchy have? And how do the keys for the  members of levels above the date level look like?

Comment: Within Completion Date.Calendar Hierarchy I have Year > Quarter Of Year  > Month Of Year > Date so members are 2014 > Q1/2014 > Jan > 2014-01-01 . Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, this is one part. The other is: What does `MemberValue` return for a month, quarter, or year? For the members of the `Date` level, it returns a date. But what does it return for the other levels, which have no unique date object associated with them. This is what is called the key.

Comment: Please excuse me my lack of knowledge. I tried to get some information on this but I'm still not sure what you mean. I thought that if for the Date level it returns date (2014-01-01) then for Month Of the Year you'll get 'Jan', for Quarter Of Year 'Q1/2014' etc., as above.

Comment: Before guessing, maybe the easiest way would be to ask the designer/administrator of the cube.